# UICloudSharingController Does not Display/Work with CloudKit App

Tags: ios, swiftui, cloudkit, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable, cloudkit-sharing

I have been struggling to get an app to work with CloudKit and record sharing. I have
created several apps that sync Core Data records among devices for one user. I have not
been able to get the UICloudSharingController to work for sharing records. I can display
the Sharing View Controller, but tapping on Mail or Message displays a keyboard but no
address field and no way to dismiss the view. I have been so frustrated by it that I
decided to try the Apple "Sharing" sample app to start from the basics. However, the
sample app does not work for me either.

Here's the link to the sample app:
https://github.com/apple/cloudkit-sample-sharing/tree/swift-concurrency

The code below is pretty much straight from the sample app.

This is the ContentView file:

```
import SwiftUI
import CloudKit

struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject private var vm: ViewModel

    @State private var isAddingContact = false
    @State private var isSharing = false
    @State private var isProcessingShare = false

    @State private var showShareView = false
    @State private var showIntermediateView = false

    @State private var activeShare: CKShare?
    @State private var activeContainer: CKContainer?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            contentView
                .navigationTitle("Contacts")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Button { Task.init { try await vm.refresh() } } label: { Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise") }
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        progressView
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button(action: { isAddingContact = true }) { Image(systemName: "plus") }
                    }
                }
        }
        .onAppear {
            Task.init {
                try await vm.initialize()
                try await vm.refresh()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isAddingContact, content: {
            AddContactView(onAdd: addContact, onCancel: { isAddingContact = false })
        })
    }

    /// This progress view will display when either the ViewModel is loading, or a share is processing.
    var progressView: some View {
        let showProgress: Bool = {
            if case .loading = vm.state {
                return true
            } else if isProcessingShare {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }()
        return Group {
            if showProgress {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
    }

    /// Dynamic view built from ViewModel state.
    private var contentView: some View {
        Group {
            switch vm.state {
            case let .loaded(privateContacts, sharedContacts):
                List {
                    Section(header: Text("Private")) {
                        ForEach(privateContacts) { contactRowView(for: $0) }
                    }
                    Section(header: Text("Shared")) {
                        ForEach(sharedContacts) { contactRowView(for: $0, shareable: false) }
                    }
                }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            
            case .error(let error):
                VStack {
                    Text("An error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)").padding()
                    Spacer()
                }
            
            case .loading:
                VStack { EmptyView() }
            }
        }
    }

    /// Builds a `CloudSharingView` with state after processing a share.
    private func shareView() -> CloudSharingView? {

        guard let share = activeShare, let container = activeContainer else {
            return nil
        }
    
        return CloudSharingView(container: container, share: share)
    }

    /// Builds a Contact row view for display contact information in a List.
    private func contactRowView(for contact: Contact, shareable: Bool = true) -> some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(contact.name)
                Text(contact.phoneNumber)
                    .textContentType(.telephoneNumber)
                    .font(.footnote)
            }
        
            if shareable {
            
                Spacer()

                Button(action: { Task.init { try? await shareContact(contact) }
                }, label: { Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up") }).buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isSharing, content: { shareView() })
            
            }//if sharable
        }//h
    }//contact row view

    // MARK: - Actions

    private func addContact(name: String, phoneNumber: String) async throws {
        try await vm.addContact(name: name, phoneNumber: phoneNumber)
        try await vm.refresh()
        isAddingContact = false
    }

    private func shareContact(_ contact: Contact) async throws {
        isProcessingShare = true
    
        do {
            let (share, container) = try await vm.createShare(contact: contact)
            isProcessingShare = false
            activeShare = share
            activeContainer = container
            isSharing = true
        } catch {
            debugPrint("Error sharing contact record: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

And the UIViewControllerRepresentable file for the sharing view:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import CloudKit

/// This struct wraps a `UIImagePickerController` for use in SwiftUI.
struct CloudSharingView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    let container: CKContainer
    let share: CKShare

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {}

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {

        let sharingController = UICloudSharingController(share: share, container: container)
        sharingController.availablePermissions = [.allowReadWrite, .allowPrivate]
        sharingController.delegate = context.coordinator
    
        return sharingController
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> CloudSharingView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }

    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UICloudSharingControllerDelegate {
    
        func cloudSharingController(_ csc: UICloudSharingController, failedToSaveShareWithError error: Error) {
            debugPrint("Error saving share: \(error)")
        }

        func itemTitle(for csc: UICloudSharingController) -> String? {
            "Sharing Example"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the presented screen when tapping to share a record. This all looks as expected:

[image]

This is the screen after tapping Messages (same result for Mail). I don't see any way to influence the second screen presentation - it seems that the view controller representable is not working with this version of Xcode:

[image]

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 13.1, iOS 15 and I am on macOS Monterrey.

Comment: Hi there, have you been able to fix this issue?

Comment: Sadly, no. I put the project on the back burner until I can figure out a way around this.

Comment: The documentation for [`UICloudSharingController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicloudsharingcontroller) clearly states: *"UICloudSharingController is designed for use in a popover. Therefore, you should always set the popoverPresentationController source information before presenting the Cloud sharing controller. Doing this ensures that the UICloudSharingController instance is displayed properly across all device types."*. This is followed by example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and fixed it by changing makeUIViewController() in CloudSharingView.swift:

```
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        share[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.title] = "Boom"
        let sharingController = UICloudSharingController(share: share, container: container)
        sharingController.availablePermissions = [.allowReadWrite, .allowPrivate]
        sharingController.delegate = context.coordinator
-->>>        sharingController.modalPresentationStyle = .none
        return sharingController
    }
```

It seems like some value work, some don't. Not sure why.

Comment: Wow. That's unbelievable. Yes indeed, the line to disable modal presentation works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a version of this issue.  Worked on iPhone & MacCatalyst without setting presentation style, but would not show on iPad.  The .none option caused iPhone & iPad to crash.  Found that using the .formSheet option works across all devices.

sharingController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet